# Как правильно выйти из цикла for?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Я в Java человек новый и мне не дает покоя один вопрос: как правильно прервать цикл?

У меня есть текстовый с полями чисел(количество полей не ограниченно), циклом "for" я читаю его и
когда цифры заканчиваются, выхожу через исключение "catch".

примерно так:

```
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("src/cache/vk" + own_Id + "/Id/Idold.txt"));
            for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i ++) {
                postIdOld [i] = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
            }
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            System.out.println("reader faile");
            break;
        } finally {
            reader.close();
        }
```

Правильно ли я делаю или есть лучше способ?

Comment: Вопрос так поставлен, что можно мозг сломать :)  Во-первых у вас цикл "for" ограничен четырьмя итерациями, и никак не вписываются в концепцию с неограниченным количеством полей. Исключение в данном случае может возникать по трём причинам: 1. Файл не найден. 2. Количество итераций не соответствует действительности. 3. Метод parseInt не находит в строке данные типа Integer. RuntimeException - исключение главного потока программы. Это "глобальное исключение" и оно неуместно.

Comment: @VitaliyM.V. Я понимаю, но я и указал это как пример. Я даже примерно не представляю, как оно должно выглядеть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ты неправильно понимаешь выход из цикла, catch и break. catch - это не выход из цикла, а блок который выполняется, если в блоке try произошло исключение, например parseInt выдало ошибку.

Что касается цикла, то он отработает у тебя 5 раз и корректно пойдет дальше, если не будет ошибок.

Чтобы прервать цикл раньше - нужно использовать break, но делать это надо *внутри* блока for. И обычно break выполняется с определенным условием, например:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i ++) {
     int parsed = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());

     // Например цикл выполняется второй раз и число больше 20
     // Тогда сработает break и цикл больше выполняться не будет
     // а программа пойдет дальше
     if(parsed > 20) {
         
         break;
     } 
     postIdOld[i] = parsed;
}
```

Если просто положить break в цикл - то выполнится всё что до break.
break вне блока цикла как у тебя в catch не используется.

Comment: "Что касается цикла, то он отработает у тебя 5 раз и корректно пойдет дальше" - Куда? :)  Он никуда дальше не пойдёт. Пройдя указанное число итераций цикл завершается. p.s. Спасибо, что поправили меня в количестве циклов в предыдущем комментарии.

Comment: После 5 раз если всё нормально, программа перейдет в блок finally. Попробуй расставить `System.out.println` везде, где не понимаешь, и посмотри что в каком порядке исполняется

Comment: @КонстантинРыбаков Да, так работает